# Why does my screen 'Wait' gets gray and only draws the components after loading the context (org.springframework.context)?

Tags: multithreading, javafx, stage, scene

Why does my screen PATH_FXML_WAIT_PROGRESS gets gray and only draws the components after loading the context? Being that the end of loading the context and it closed.

When I run the app, my progress screen opens while loading the spring context. But the screen is all gray without the components drawn on it. The same will be drawn only after the context has finished loading, but when the task is completed successfully, the progress window closes, and the login window is opened through its controller, which has been instantiated by spring, give forward is all normal.

I wanted a way to display the progress being drawn while the connection charge and continue working normally. If I use another thread, multiple errors are shown to instantiate some classes AVFinalConfig.

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stageApp) {
    LOG.info("Starting App...");

    Task<Void> taskContext = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AVFinalConfig.class);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void failed() {
            super.failed();
            LOG.error(getException().getMessage(), getException());
            getException().printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded() {
            super.succeeded();
            stageApp.close();
            openLogin();
        }
    };

    openWaitProgress(stageApp);
    Platform.runLater(taskContext);
}

private void openWaitProgress(Stage stageApp) {
    try {
        final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(Constants.PATH_FXML_WAIT_PROGRESS.valuesToString()));
        Parent parentLoad = fxmlLoader.load();
        stageApp.setScene(new Scene(parentLoad));
        stageApp.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stageApp.centerOnScreen();
        stageApp.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        new MessageDisplay(stageApp.getScene().getRoot(), Constants.MSG_ERROR_GENERIC.valuesToString()).showErrorMessage();
    }
}

private void openLogin() {
    final LoginController loginController = context.getBean(LoginController.class);
    try {
        loginController.show();
        loginController.stagePrimary.setOnCloseRequest(event -> context.close());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error(Constants.MSG_ERROR_GENERIC.valuesToString(), e);
        new MessageDisplay(loginController.stagePrimary.getScene().getRoot(), Constants.MSG_ERROR_GENERIC.valuesToString()).showErrorMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are running everything on the FX Application Thread, so there is no opportunity to create the UI for your "wait progress" until your `Task`'s `call()` method has completed.

Instead of scheduling the Task on the FX Application Thread, run it on a background thread:

```
// Platform.runLater(taskContext);
new Thread(taskContext).start();
```

or (this version will make sure the thread does not prevent the application from exiting):

```
Thread t = new Thread(taskContext);
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it always returns me this error I could not solve: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3

Cause by:
br.com.avfinal.configuration.AVFinalConfig.stagePrimary(AVFinalConfig.java:17)

public class AVFinalConfig {

 @Bean
 Stage stagePrimary() {
  return new Stage();
 }

}

Comment: That looks like you are trying to create a `Stage` from your background thread, which is illegal. You need to create the stage back in your `succeeded()` method.

Comment: but even though I solve this problem of the Stage, other injection problems of Spring will occur.

Comment: That's probably too vague for anyone to be able to help. The bottom line is you need to separate your non-UI, time-consuming work (which should be performed in the Task, on a background thread) from your UI work (which must be performed on the FX Application Thread). You should be able to initialize your Spring context without creating any UI components: even if you use Spring to manage those, have them be created on demand, and request them from the context on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: Resolved: Thread t = new Thread(taskContext); t.setDaemon(true); t.start();........ and public class AVFinalConfig {

 private Stage stage;

 @Bean
 Stage stagePrimary() {
  PlatformImpl.runAndWait(() -> stage = new Stage());
  return stage;
 }

}

Comment: I strongly recommend finding a different solution. You are using non-public API (there is no guarantee `PlatformImpl.runAndWait(...)` will be available in future releases) and your code is probably prone to deadlock.